# Using a new statement in the control part of the for loop

Tags: c#, coding-style

What's the verdict on replacing:

```
Regex exp = new Regex(MyReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var matches = exp.Matches(source);
foreach (var m in matches)
      ...
```

With:

```
foreach (var m in new Regex(MyReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Matches(source))
      ...
```

Performance issues, slower, unreadable? Or OK?

Comment: Surely this question should be on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...?

Comment: For speed optimizations, see [this post](http://kurtschindler.net/blog/post/Regular-expression-performance-comparisons)

Comment: Thanks, I'd never heard of codereview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn’t bother with constructing the redundant `Regex` object in the first place. Just use the static method:

```
foreach (var m in Regex.Matches(source, MyReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    // ...
```

This is both the fastest and the most readable that it will get.

Comment: Careful, that 'redundant' instance costs absolutely nothing. There is nothing 'fastest' about this version. And it is usually prudent to cache a RegEx whenever you can.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer your first version for readability. Your second version puts too much on one line and I find that quite difficult to work out what is going on.

Also, if you have an error somewhere in this, it is much easier to debug with the first version.

Comment: Your second argument is sound, but the first one is surely weak: *I* don’t find it difficult to work out at all. How are you going to infer from yourself to other developers? Where do you draw the line if someone finds *anything* difficult to work out?

Comment: He was also asking about readability. That is mostly opinion, and I do find the second version more difficult to read. It is more densely compacted together which I find more difficult to read. In a team environment it is best to write stuff that the majority can parse quickly.

Comment: And, where do you draw the line? No idea - ask your team what they prefer. They are going to be working with it, so they must be comfortable with it.

Comment: @Timwi Readability is a matter of preference, you have to find something you and your team can agree on.  FWIW I agree with Colin.

Answer (score 2):

Overall performance should be the same. Readability suffers a little IMO, but it's not too bad really. So I would, subjectively, say that it's ok.

Comment: I think readability benefits. The first version is too verbose. It also declares local variables that may or may not be used again later. The second one usefully limits the scope of the regular-expression object, so there’s much less to worry about. It also reads very fluently.

Comment: Which is, as you pointed out with my answer, just your opinion